# Convert Django model array into alpine.js array

Tags: python, django, alpine.js

I try to convert Django model ArrayField into Alpine.js array. How to solve this problem?

```
 x-on:click="offer_1 = !offer_1; currentJob={
                   title: '{{ job.title }}',
                    responsibilities: [{{ job.responsibilities }}] ???????,
                   }">
```

and then I want display it:

```
 <template x-for="responsibility in responsibilities">
              <li
                class="text-sm text-darkPurple font-light pl-5 bg-[url('../img/plus.svg')] bg-no-repeat bg-[top_4px_left] mb-4"
                x-text="responsibility">
              </li>
            </template>
```

Answer (score 2):

Django has a similar filter called [`json_script`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/_modules/django/utils/html/) however it produces a `<script id="data" type="application/json">{"hello": "world"}</script>` string that can be inserted into the template. We can modify it to produce an inline escaped JSON that can be passed to an Alpine.js variable.

Create a new [custom filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-filters) in the `templatetags` folder of your app (e.g. `myapp_extras.py`):

```
import json

from django import template
from django.core.serializers.json import DjangoJSONEncoder
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe

register = template.Library()

_json_script_escapes = {
    ord(">"): "\\u003E",
    ord("<"): "\\u003C",
    ord("&"): "\\u0026",
}

@register.filter
def to_json(value):
    json_str = json.dumps(value, cls=DjangoJSONEncoder).translate(_json_script_escapes)

    return mark_safe(json_str)
```

And in the template we load our custom filter and use on the array:

```
{% load myapp_extras %}

<a @click="currentJob={ responsibilities: {{ job.responsibilities|to_json }} }">
```

It becomes something like this after rendering:

```
<a @click="currentJob={ responsibilities: ['String #1', 'String #2'] }">
```